# how to calculate the distance from 1 row to the next row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

need help, I need to calculate the distance from the first row to the next row and so on.
I have a table like below

**table example**

| id | period | user_id | action | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-14 02:29:26 | 110 | run background | -6.280288219451904 | 106.82013702392578 |
| 2 | 2022-10-14 03:29:26 | 120 | run background | -6.281721591949463 | 106.82991790771484 |
| 3 | 2022-10-14 04:29:26 | 110 | run background | -6.280627250671387 | 106.82881927490234 |
| 4 | 2022-10-14 05:29:26 | 120 | run background | -6.280624866485596 | 106.82881927490234 |

And the result should look like this:

[expected result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNct.png)

| id | period | user_id | action | latitude | longitude | to_latitude | to_longitude | distance_meters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-14 02:29:26 | 110 | run background | -6.280 | 106.820 | -6.288 | 106.828 | 50 |
| 3 | 2022-10-14 04:29:26 | 110 | run background | -6.288 | 106.828 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2022-10-14 03:29:26 | 120 | run background | -6.281 | 106.829 | -6.283 | 106.829 | 55 |
| 4 | 2022-10-14 05:29:26 | 120 | run background | -6.283 | 106.829 |  |  |  |

I've tried several queries, but didn't find any good results
This is an example of the query I'm using

```
 SELECT 
      datetime(t1.created_at) period
     , t1.user_id
     , t1.action
     , t1.Latitude AS LatFrom
     , t1.Longitude AS LongFrom
     , t2.Latitude AS LatTo
     , t2.Longitude AS LongTo
FROM geolocation t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN geolocation t2 ON t2.promotor_id=t1.promotor_id AND t2.id > t1.id
WHERE 
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
Order by 1
```

Please help my friends, thank you in advance

Comment: MySQL or Google BigQuery? They're not the same thing.

Comment: yes for sql Bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below (BigQuery)

```
select *, 
  lead(latitude) over win as to_latitude, 
  lead(longitude) over win as to_longitude,
  st_distance(
    st_geogpoint(longitude, latitude), 
    lead(st_geogpoint(longitude, latitude)) over win
  ) as distance_meters
from your_table
window win as (partition by user_id order by period)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: So I want to ask something , if I want to calculate the distance from the previous row, do I need to use the LAG function?
that's what i read in the documentation

Comment: that's right. lag will do the work!